# OSB 11g returns the same request payload as the response

Tags: osb

I've configured a service in OSB 11g and for some reason when I invoke the service through OSB I get the same exact request XML payload as the response. SOAPUI log shows 200 status code but I am not sure why it displays the request payload as the response.

I don't see any stack trace unless I am missing otherwise I would've posted it here. Any guidance on how to resolve this.

Proxy service routes to business service as show in the screen shot below.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Did you replace $body in the return pipeline? If the proxy pipeline does not route anywhere, it will hit the bottom and return the request as the response unless it's set to something else.

Comment: I have configured the route from proxy to hit the business service.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a default behavior of the pipeline. The **default route node is an echo node** that reflects the request as the response.

See Oracle Service Bus Documentation, e.g. paragraph 2.2.3 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15020/architecture_overview.htm#OSBCA153).

Comment: KarelHUsa, what should I do to fix this then?

Comment: KarelHusa. I've updated my question with the screenshot. So my proxy service routes to business services.

Answer (score 0):

As said by KarelHusa in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098245/osb-11g-returns-the-same-request-payload-as-the-response/47132162#47132162), echo action is the default action for empty pipeline. Unfortunately, this is not always the case. While working with OSB I had at least two situatuions where I got request payload as a response.

The first situation occurred during stress testing of our project (we were sending requests to OSB from parallel threads) - OSB happened to return request payload as a response when to many parallel requests arrived.

The second situation was 'more obvious' - OSB server got stuck in state 'admin' instead of 'running' (due to database problems, well explained [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6407)) - in this case errors were logged to a logfile (however stating that JMS connection is unreachable).

What I want to point out by this answer is that it's not always the problem with invalid pipeline/route configuration, sometimes there may be an underlying cause and it is worth to check all logfiles for errors, not only the server.log for specific server node.